# Issues trying to install gnome-control-center

Tags: apt, gnome, gnome-control-center

Trying to reinstall gncome control center and keep getting the following issue:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-control-center : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.25.2) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-control-center-data (< 1:3.37) but 1:40.0-1ubuntu5 is to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.25.3) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: network-manager-gnome (>= 0.9.8) but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-control-center-faces but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: rygel but it is not going to be installed or
                                    rygel-tracker but it is not going to be installed
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:16
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:15 and /etc/apt/sources.list:17
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Your output shows two independent problems: The version conflict ("*held broken packages*") and the duplicated sources (*is configured multiple times*). Both are self-inflicted, and both have been asked and answered many times. Try the Search box at the top of the page. After you understand the errors you made, both are easily fixed.

Comment: Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/124466) answer.

Comment: Your eccentric package versioning does not match any known Ubuntu versioning.